# Use jquery ui autocomplete to search JSON output in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to search my users table using the jquery ui autocomplete widget.
The two fields from my users table, which I would like to search for:

```
TABLE `users`
 `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
```

**The view**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/friend/showFriends", //the function in the controller
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var data = $(response).map(function(){
                return {value: this.friend_usernames}; //I am pretty sure this is not correct?
            }).get();
            console.log(data);

        $("#searchFriends").autocomplete({
          source: data,
          minLength: 1
        });
      });
    });
});
</script>

<input type="search" id="searchFriends" placeholder="find friends"/>
```

**The controller**

```
/**
 * Show friends
 */
 public function showFriends()
 {
     $this->View->render('friend/index', array(
         'privateFriends' => FriendModel::displayFriends(),
         'searchFriends' => FriendModel::searchUsers()
      ));
 }
```

**The model**

```
/**
 * Search users table
 */
public static function searchUsers()
{
//if(isset($_GET['term'])) { /* Commented out for testing */
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

    $query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_name LIKE :term or user_email LIKE :term) ORDER BY user_id LIMIT 5");

    $query->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    $friends = $query->fetchAll();

    $friend_usernames = array(); 

    foreach($friends as $friend) { 
            $friend_usernames[] = $friend->user_name;
            $friend_usernames[] = $friend->user_email;
        }

    /* output results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($friend_usernames);
    //}
}
```

**The Output**

> Notice: Undefined index: term 
>   ["user1","user1@email.com","user2","user2@email.com"]

So I am able to output the JSON on the site, however I am not able to search it with the autocomplete widget!
Can anybody help me out, please?
I am not using any kind of framework or cms.
I would be very happy about any kind of help!

Comment: maybe you should return your `json_encode($friend_usernames)` instead of echo. If that doesnt work, try hardcoding a Javascript array to make sure the autocomplete works on itself

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Return instead of echo did not help. I will try out your second suggestion now.

Comment: The autocomplete on its own is working. I have the feeling that this part is where the problem lies: var data = $(response).map(function(){
                return {value: this.friend_usernames};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thoroughly checked your problem and finally solved it.The main problem is your json format is not comming properly.It should come in this format to work properly -

```
[
    {
        "user_name": "user1",
        "user_email": "user1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "user_name": "user2",
        "user_email": "user2@email.com"
    }
]
```

Somehow I produced the json with the help of PHP not by database,whatever may be,it is coming through the 'url' part via AJAX.

Well to check via php I am giving the code for testing ---

data.php

```
<?php 
$friend=array(
        array("user_name"=>"user1","user_email"=>"user1@email.com"),
        array("user_name"=>"user2","user_email"=>"user2@email.com")
        );

        echo json_encode($friend);

?>
```

and the complete html and javascript code together is

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var data=[];

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php", //the function in the controller
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            //console.log(response);
            $.each(response, function(i,val){
            data.push(""+val.user_name+"");//to display names in auto-complete
            data.push(""+val.user_email+"");//to display emails in auto-complete
        });

        },
      });


$("#searchFriends").focus(function(){
             $("#searchFriends").autocomplete({
                        autoFocus: true,
                        source:data,
                        minLength: 1, 
                        select: function(event, ui){
                            //do something
                            //autofocus:true
                            },
                         autoFocus: true,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        html: false,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",2000);
                            }

                        });

        }).change(function() {
        if($('#searchFriends').val() != $('#searchFriends').data('selected-item')) {
            if($('.ui-autocomplete').length) {
                //$("#searchFriends").val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <input type="search" id="searchFriends" class="form-control" placeholder="find friends" autocomplete="on"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So,that's it and it's working properly.
To test it ---

1> Create an 'index.html' file and copy the html and javascript code into it,all the links are taken from cdn,just all you need is internet coinnection.

2> Create an 'data.php' file and copy the php code into it and keep this file in same folder with 'index.html'.No database required(for testing purpose).

3>Run it.

N.B.*** To get result with your database you need to make your incoming json format like what I given above.

And I hope finally it's done.Thanks.

Comment: In the test it is working! In my project not just yet. But you are right about my json format, so I am pretty sure as soon as I figure out how to get the format right it is going to work in my project too! Finally I know, what the problem is and now I know what to research! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

First set  autocomplete="on" to your input field i.e.

```
<input type="search" id="searchFriends" placeholder="find friends" autocomplete="on"/>
```

Then write javascript as

```
$("#searchFriends").focus(function(){

             $("#searchFriends").autocomplete({
                        autoFocus: true,
                        source:data,
                        minLength: 3, //search after two characters
                        select: function(event, ui){
                            //do something
                            //autofocus:true
                            },
                         autoFocus: true,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        html: false,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",2000);
                            }

                        });

        }).change(function() {
        if($('#searchFriends').val() != $('#searchFriends').data('selected-item')) {
            if($('.ui-autocomplete').length) {
                //$("#searchFriends").val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

and keep it in $(document).ready(function(){.....});

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it still does not work. I also do not see where it would call the controller function? Source is set to data or how does that work?

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! If you could help me over this last hurdle, I would be beyond thankful!

Comment: have you loaded jquery auto-complete plugin and keep the code inside the $(document).ready(function(){.....}); ?

Comment: i have changed only the auto-complete function,rest is same what you did,well I am posting the full javascript again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data=[];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/friend/showFriends", //the function in the controller
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            $.each(response, function(i,val){
            data.push(""+val.friend_usernames+"");
        });

        },
      });


$("#searchFriends").focus(function(){

             $("#searchFriends").autocomplete({
                        autoFocus: true,
                        source:data,
                        minLength: 3, //search after two characters
                        select: function(event, ui){
                            //do something
                            //autofocus:true
                            },
                         autoFocus: true,
                        mustMatch: true,
                        html: false,
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index",2000);
                            }

                        });

        }).change(function() {
        if($('#searchFriends').val() != $('#searchFriends').data('selected-item')) {
            if($('.ui-autocomplete').length) {
                //$("#searchFriends").val('');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and HTML

```
<input type="search" id="searchFriends" placeholder="find friends" autocomplete="on"/>
```

That's all I can do.This works for me fine,though for other database,make sure you are getting json properly from AJAX call and you have jquery-autocomplete plugin and jquery-ui-custom.x.x.x.js along with jquery auto-complete css plugin.

Comment: Thank you!! I missunderstood your code. I used it instead of mine. That is why it did not make any sense to me. Now, it makes more sense. Unfortunately, still does not solve my problem. Thank you though for all your effort!